# How to bind ProgressBar visibility with ImageView using databinding

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-jetpack

Can any one tell me how to bind progressbar visibility with imageview using databinding when image upload so hide progress bar

Answer (score 0):

If you change progressbar visibility using databinding, then you can change imageview visibility using same logic, but inverted.
Code snipped of layout may help to offer concrete solution

Comment: i did not find any detailed documents regarding data binding in which worked on two way complex data binding so if you know then please share me any specific article which can clear my concept because one way and two way data binding i can do instead of complex binding

Comment: There is no need for complex databinding
For example,
<ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="@{viewmodel.isLoading ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"/>

so, you can use same viewmodel.isLoading property to bind imageview visibility